# Google calendar updating event - Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I have some problems with updating events for Google calendar with the API. I'm trying to implement it as descibed here: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingEvents

I'm not sure what headers and body need to be attached to the request. The headers I'm sending are:

```
'header'    => array(
    'Content-Type'      => 'application/json',
    'If-Match'      => '*',
    'GData-Version'     => 2
)
```

basicly, this is my request:

```
Array
(
[method] => PUT
[uri] => Array
    (
        [scheme] => https
        [host] => www.google.com
        [port] => 443
        [user] => 
        [pass] => 
        [path] => /calendar/feeds/6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full/8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss_20111117T140000Z
        [query] => Array
            (
            )

        [fragment] => 
    )

[version] => 1.1
[body] => {"apiVersion":"1.0","data":{"kind":"calendar#event","id":"8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss_20111117T140000Z","selfLink":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/feeds\/6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8%40group.calendar.google.com\/private\/full\/8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss_20111117T140000Z","alternateLink":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/event?eid=OHZwZzFoYThvYWhpbjhsN2swc3ZnOGt0c3NfMjAxMTExMTdUMTQwMDAwWiA2b2tuOW9ycWNxNWtnZDJrdHNzdnE2NzVrOEBn","canEdit":true,"title":"hihi","created":"2011-10-25T16:15:18.000Z","updated":"2011-11-10T13:54:27.000Z","details":"titel: \"Paintball vrouwen evenement\"\nbeschrijving: \"Dit evenement is enkele voor vrouwen\"\npersonen: \"33\"\ngroepen: \"12\"\nstatus: \"auto\"\npopulair: \"nee\"\n","status":"confirmed","creator":{"displayName":"--@gmail.com","email":"--@gmail.com"},"anyoneCanAddSelf":false,"guestsCanInviteOthers":true,"guestsCanModify":false,"guestsCanSeeGuests":true,"sequence":2,"transparency":"opaque","visibility":"private","location":"Paintball","attendees":[{"rel":"organizer","displayName":"website","email":"6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8@group.calendar.google.com"}],"when":[{"start":"2011-11-17T10:00:00.000Z","end":"2011-11-17T12:00:00.000Z"}],"originalEvent":{"href":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/feeds\/6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8%40group.calendar.google.com\/private\/full\/8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss","id":"8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss","start":"2011-11-17T14:00:00.000Z"}}}
[line] => PUT /calendar/feeds/6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full/8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss_20111117T140000Z HTTP/1.1

[header] => Host: www.google.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Content-Type: application/json
If-Match: *
Content-Length: 1457

[raw] => PUT /calendar/feeds/6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full/8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss_20111117T140000Z HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: CakePHP
Content-Type: application/json
If-Match: *
Content-Length: 1457

{"apiVersion":"1.0","data":{"kind":"calendar#event","id":"8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss_20111117T140000Z","selfLink":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/feeds\/6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8%40group.calendar.google.com\/private\/full\/8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss_20111117T140000Z","alternateLink":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/event?eid=OHZwZzFoYThvYWhpbjhsN2swc3ZnOGt0c3NfMjAxMTExMTdUMTQwMDAwWiA2b2tuOW9ycWNxNWtnZDJrdHNzdnE2NzVrOEBn","canEdit":true,"title":"hihi","created":"2011-10-25T16:15:18.000Z","updated":"2011-11-10T13:54:27.000Z","details":"titel: \"Paintball vrouwen evenement\"\nbeschrijving: \"Dit evenement is enkele voor vrouwen\"\npersonen: \"33\"\ngroepen: \"12\"\nstatus: \"auto\"\npopulair: \"nee\"\n","status":"confirmed","creator":{"displayName":"--@gmail.com","email":"--@gmail.com"},"anyoneCanAddSelf":false,"guestsCanInviteOthers":true,"guestsCanModify":false,"guestsCanSeeGuests":true,"sequence":2,"transparency":"opaque","visibility":"private","location":"Paintball","attendees":[{"rel":"organizer","displayName":"website","email":"6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8@group.calendar.google.com"}],"when":[{"start":"2011-11-17T10:00:00.000Z","end":"2011-11-17T12:00:00.000Z"}],"originalEvent":{"href":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/calendar\/feeds\/6okn9orqcq5kgd2ktssvq675k8%40group.calendar.google.com\/private\/full\/8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss","id":"8vpg1ha8oahin8l7k0svg8ktss","start":"2011-11-17T14:00:00.000Z"}}}
[cookies] => Array
    (
    )

[proxy] => Array
    (
    )

[auth] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

this is the response I get with a 400 status:

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.

so , im obviously doing something wrong, anyone knows what?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the PHP tag you placed, I assume you are using PHP. Are you using the Zend Gdata framework? If yes you have more information here: https://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html

Are you using the save() method?

Can you provide us with the piece of code you are using? If you give me that I'll edit this answer to give you the corrected version of your update.

Comment: the problem had to do with the Oauth I was using and the parameters in the URL. Im using Cakephp 2.0 so i cant use the zend Gdata framework. This question is solved now by using Oauth the correct way. I have another problem though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099880/google-api-with-params-gives-unknown-authorization-header